# Text based cipher I assume based on grammatical error

Tags: cipher

[image]

Anyone had experience in this regard? I've arranged what I think to be the obvious errors but can't find any obvious pattern.

Text version of image:

> dear diary    96 Olmoon 26
>
> i have been spen ding my time reflecting on My recent life
> experience for nights now. everything has changed so
> quickly since i joined the soc iety. i moved to the secret
> headquarter just three months ago, Yet i feel like i've lived
> in this envIronment for much loNger. the other recr uited
> members seem like good people, they are all courteous and
> polite, and out bond is growing stroNger, there is a feeling
> that torm3nts me though, as if someone weRe watching us,
> uninterruptedly. i feel as if my every movement is being
> monitored, anAlyzed and studied in detail. or maybe it's just
> an impre ssion, due to the atmosphere you breathe here.
> anyway tomorroW is a great day, they have entrusted us with
> an expedition in the desert, we must investig4te the traces
> left by an ancient civilizaKtion, recover the archa3ological
> remaiNs, and obtain as much 1 nformation as possible.  i caN't
> wait Get to know the hidden secrets behind it.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour]! Could you please provide [proper attribution](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/proper-attribution-for-non-original-puzzles-a-guide) for this question? Also, could you please transcribe the text?

Comment: I've added a text version, as I transcribed it for solving anyway. Hopefully I haven't added any typos beyond those in the original text.

Answer (score 5):

Highlighting the "interesting" bits of text.

> If we ignore the many missing capitals, and the odd extra spaces, and focus just on the unnecessary capitals and l33t sp34k, what do we get:
>
> > dear diary                                 90 Olmoon 26
> >
> >  i have been spen ding my time reflecting on **M**y recent life
> >  experience for nights now. everything has changed so
> >  quickly since i joined the soc iety. i moved to the secret
> >  headquarter just three months ago, **Y**et i feel like i've lived
> >  in this env**I**ronment for much lo**N**ger. the other recr uited
> >  members seem like good people, they are all courteous and
> >  polite, and out bond is growing stro**N**ger, there is a feeling
> >  that torm**3**nts me though, as if someone we**R**e watching us,
> >  uninterruptedly. i feel as if my every movement is being
> >  monitored, an**A**lyzed and studied in detail. or maybe it's just
> >  an impre ssion, due to the atmosphere you breathe here.
> >  anyway tomorro**W** is a great day, they have entrusted us with
> >  an expedition in the desert, we must investig**4**te the traces
> >  left by an ancient civiliza**K**tion, recover the archa**3**ological
> >  remai**N**s, and obtain as much **1** nformation as possible.  i ca**N**'t
> >  wait **G**et to know the hidden secrets behind it.

And that gives us:

> **MYINN3RAW4K3N1NG**
>  or
>  **My inner awakening**